# Sorting OrderedEnumerableRowCollection .. strings like 00-000, 01-000 are not sorted as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.data

i've got some records from a query like this

SortingCode (column)
Row: 00-005
Row: 00-000

the folowing code, doesn't sort this ...

```
var items = 
    from c in table
    orderby c.SortingCode
    select c;
```

Comment: What do you get, and what did you except?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to explain what result you are expecting, because the following code

```
var items = new List<string>() { "00-005", "01-004", "00-003" };

foreach (var item in items.OrderBy(i => i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Do output

```
00-003
00-005
01-004
```

Which seem well sorted for me. What result are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry,

I use multiple columns that needs to be sorted ... I've fixed it by doing this:

var items = 
    (from c in table
    select c).OrderBy(row => row.SortingCode).ThenBy(row => row.Description).ThenBy ....;

This works fine for me
Thx for your reactions and quick support